# Выбор фреймворка для модульной программы

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp

Добрый день.

Мне предстоит написать небольшое веб-приложение на JSP и в дальнейшем его поддерживать. До этого я не писал на Java. Мне нужен совет по выбору фреймворка. Программа однозначно должна быть модульной.

Comment: @ssh, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Какое приложение? Какого вида модули? Штатный экстрасенс в отпуске, так что вам придётся дать хоть немного конкретики.

Comment: @fori1ton, Корпоративная CRM. Не очень сложная, всё стандартно: клиенты, документы, счета, немножко аналитики. Система уже написана и работает на JSP. Но на выходе страницы почти целиком строятся на javascript. Его реально много и чтобы написать поиск по документам, приходится править js в 20 местах. Система почти полностью состоит из костылей. Собираюсь переписать все с нуля.

Comment: Нужно, чтобы можно было быстро добавлять нужную функциональность. Вот я и спрашиваю про архитектуру. Как её построить так, чтобы потом можно было легко с ней работать. Я поискал в интернете, ничего не нашел. Я думаю, что было бы здорово использовать прадигму MVC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почитайте книжку под названием Spring in action - есть на русском языке, притом объеденены 2-е и 3-е издание на сколько я помню. Лично мне подход, который там описан нравится.

Думаю после прочтения вы ответите на свой вопрос :) это что касается серверной части.

А от javascript я вам избавляться не советую, так как очень удобно совершать действия без перезагрузки страницы и в каких-то местах вообще без обращения к серверу. Для js тоже есть много удобных фреймворков, которые позволят вам сделать хорошее модульное приложение. Мне больше всего понравился angularjs, но есть и другие аналоги.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC или Struts

Comment: @Svensen, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

Если не писали на Java, то лучше не надо писать. Для JSP надо знать основы, без них никуда.